# Can Brahmin be a teacher on any other topics other than Vedas

Tags: dharma, brahmins

I have read that the prescribed duties of brahmin are becomings priests, learning and teaching so I want to clarify this doubt.

Comment: Related: [Can the Guna-Karma classification of the Varna system be translated into profession?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12320/1049). --- A person with *Brahmana* traits is the best suited for **any kind of teachings**. In ancient times, it were Vedas etc; in modern times it's today's relevant topics.

Comment: Yes medicine. Ethics. HR. Arts and many

Comment: what do you mean by 'other than vedas'? all topics needed for society to function - yagna for rains, dhanur vidya for fighting, go-krishi for cows & agriculture - are all present in vedas and veda-angas. and brahmins are the ones supposed to be teaching these, but not actually using it themselves to earn, but only get dakshina for teaching. for modern day, you can replace with appropriate changes like tractor instead of plough, but concept remains same. nowadays, more importantly, teaching the science of salvation is their main duty, since that can neither be replaced, nor avoided.

Comment: No I am Bhramin by birth,I have read BE computer science.I am also reading vedas.I just asked this question so I can get involved in teaching profession and also I will follow the rule that a Bhramin should always subsist without expecting much money soo.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently **Yes**.

See the following verse from the Manu Smriti:

> 10.75. Teaching, studying, sacrificing for himself, sacrificing for others, making gifts and receiving them are the six acts (prescribed)
>   for a Brahmana.

In the Sanskrit Shloka, the word used, which is translated as "teaching", is **adhyApanam**. Now, even the [word for a professor/teacher](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=adhyApakaH&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) in Sanskrit will be adhyApaka or "one who does adhyApanam"

So, apparently yes.

Comment: We also have direct examples from Itihasas and puranas where Brahmins taught many vidyas besides Vedas.

Comment: In Itihasas and Puranas we find depiction of what happened in the past. It is not necessary that all those events are approved as per the laws. FOr e.g. even when gods like Rama, Krishna ate meat, drank alcohol, people ask whether those acts are lawful or not. So, what to say of the acts done by the other characters? And eventually we resort to these Smritis to find out whether those acts are approved or not. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Gods like Rama, Krishna do not go immoral and unlawful act. Dharma differs with situation and time. We should not follow literally what is written in the smritis every time. If they do, there will be a definite reason for that. What I meant is there are many people in the epics and puranas who taught _following_ the law not against it. Drona comes to mind first. He taught archery to many. I said something and you understand and and reply something else unrelated. Pfft.. Do you ever take my comment in the way I intended?

Comment: I did not reply to something else.. You did not understand what i meant.. I made it clear that Drona doing something does not prove that it was the right thing done (at least it does not prove anything for me) .. we need to check if it was allowed or not from the Smritis .. so i won't include such examples in my answer. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Rickross "In Itihasas and Puranas we find depiction of what happened in the past" No, they sometimes talk about laws as well..and if it's difficult to survive in own Varna one can do the work of lower Varna's...if it's hard to survive then Bhramin can do Kashtriya (teaching the knowledge of weapons, participating in Dharmyudha) tasks or even tasks of other lower Varna's...

Comment: Yes i know that but why are u saying all these to me here? @YDS

Comment: Bcz Ur comment somehow shows that Itihas Puranas are not Valid at all..this Q is answered in Puranas and that's not a story of past but talking on law...

Comment: My comment does not imply that Puranas are not "valid".. I hv never said that..  Now if u felt that way what can i do? @YDS

Comment: @Rickross okay.. however I hv seen Ur same comment in many Questions.. and few people might feel same as me.. but if U didn't mean that then u don't need to do anything.. :)

Answer (score 4):

As per **Chapter 2 (Varnashrama Dharma) of Kurma Purana**, there are six types of action that are recommended for brahmanas. These are

1. yajana (performing sacrifices),
2. yaajana (acting as priests at sacrifices),
3. dana (donation of alms),
4. pratigraha (receiving gifts),
5. adhyapana (teaching) and
6. adhyayana (studying).

> [image]
> [image]

It doesn't have the word Vedas specifically. Moreover, as per [Varna Ashrama chapter of Brahma Purana](https://archive.org/stream/BrahmaPuranaTranishJhaComplete/Brahma%20Purana%20Tranish%20Jha%20%28Complete%29#page/n1244/mode/1up),

> **In times of emergency**, a brahmana is allowed to adopt the livelihoods
> of kshatriyas or vaishyas to earn a living.
>
> [image]

---

**Related**

[Drona and his dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/drona-and-his-dharma)