Guide for Brahmins
Is there any book or guide related to the daily conduct of Brahmins?
Covering day to day activities, mantras , how-to-articles (yagna, Puja etc) , methodologies, basically everything a janeu dhari Brahmin needs to know.
References would also be appreciated if any!
Thank you!

Some nice answers: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27743/what-are-duties-and-goals-of-a-brahmin-and-how-should-he-behave
